# Multipage Flexdashboard with Shiny runtime -how to detect page change within shiny module observer

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am wondering if there is a way to detect a page change using an observer in flexdashboard with a shiny runtime environment? I would like to observe a page change then force evaluation of another observer, or, if easier, force evaluation a reactive data object inside a shiny module. The present design has a couple of graphs and stuff on the first page, all generated from the reactive `dat()` object, and then a leaflet map on the second page of the flexdashboard, that uses the same `dat()` object. The issue is that my present observer does not fire the first time a user clicks on the page, despite being setup to run via `observeEvent(dat(), {plotting code here})`. After they make a new data selection, however, the `dat()` observer fires off, thereby producing the desired results and expected leaflet plots.

I would like to solve the issue of the map being blank the first time the user clicks on the second page. I have tried looking on RStudio's docs, but maybe I have missed something.  I'm hoping someone could help me with this. Thank you in advance, Nate.

Comment: Haven't been able to find anything that solves this issue still.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what is amiss w/o a `reprex`, but I would guess that the plot output is not rendered because it is on a hidden page. Maybe

```
outputOptions(output, "myplot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

would help with `myplot` equal to the `id` of your leaflet map output object?

Comment: I tried it, but it made the map freeze and not load anything. I'm using a module to load the map (with a proxy for updates) and think I may be bumping into this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1731 ... I'll post a full `reprex` later this week as soon as I can get around to it. I really do appreciate your help. Thank you.